# Locating boundaries of memory segments in C++

Tags: c++, linux, windows, memory, segment

When compiling a C++ program on Linux or Windows, what is best way to locate the boundaries of each of the memory segments (e.g. .bss, .data, .rodata, .text) ?

Are there ways to do this at runtime within the C++ program itself, or can this only be done by inspecting the binary from the command line ?

Comment: Why would you want to know them? There is very little you can do with them from inside the program... if this is for a specific executable, the easiest way would be to have the linker tell you, by means of a linker script... is that what you're after?

Comment: When I define a variable and check it's address, I want to understand in which segment it has been placed. Potentially the linker script is what I need. If I am compiling with GCC / G++ from the command line, is there an easy way to access the linker script to see this information ?

Comment: Again, why does it matter from which segment it came? A linker script could *change* that, for example, and it's implementation-defined in the first place... documentation on linker scripts, and how to have the linker set symbols you can then use in the program, can be found on [OSDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/Linker_Scripts#Symbols).

Comment: You could also use a combination of `nm`, `objdump`, and `readelf` to figure out what goes where.

Comment: @DevSolar I ask this question because I have read that a `constexpr` variable when initialized with a constant expression will be stored in ROM. I have also read that this is useful for embedded systems development. Therefore, I want to experiment to understand the concept better.

Comment: @thatmarkdude: ROM means a chip... I guess you mean .rodata. As I said, whether your value will be in .data, .rodata, or .text depends on the linker script used. If you do not specify one, the system will use the default script, and that may be a different one from that used by your embedded platform. A `constexpr` *should* end up in `.rodata`, but... yea.